# Widen bars in plot by pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, axis

A seemingly simple question that I could not figure out.
Pgfplots uses very narrow bars in the following image. How can I make them wider?
Ideally, they should also be closer together. I just want to make use of the available space...

[image]

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354519/how-to-automatically-fit-many-bars-in-barchart-using-pgfplots), I was already able  to get fairly close to what I want.

[image]

However, there is still some space wasted on the left and the right side...

**Edit**: Apparently, this is possible using `enlarge x limits={abs=1,rel=0.4}`.

---

Code for the first Figure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    x & y & z \\
    0        & 1       & 2           \\
    1        & 3      & 1           \\
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
%bar width=2cm,
legend columns=2, 
legend style={at={(0.5,1.12)},anchor=north},
symbolic x coords={0,1},
xtick={0,1}
]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y]{\data};
\addplot table[x=x,y=z]{\data};
\legend{y, z}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Code for the second Figure:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    x & y & z \\
    0        & 1       & 2           \\
    1        & 3      & 1           \\
}\data

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
width=5cm,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
bar width=11,
enlarge x limits={abs=1},
legend columns=2, 
legend style={at={(0.5,1.22)},anchor=north},
xtick=data
]
\addplot table[x=x,y=y]{\data};
\addplot table[x=x,y=z]{\data};
\legend{y, z}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the [comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401242/w#comment999264_401242) the answer to your question can be found elsewhere, which you also tried to adapt. But you missed to set a proper `compat` level, so you can give `bar width` in axis units.

Please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % use this `compat' level or higher to be able
        % to give `bar width' in axis units
        compat=1.7,
    }
    \pgfplotstableread[
        row sep=\\,
        col sep=&,
    ]{
        x & y & z \\
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        1 & 3 & 1 \\
    }\data
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ybar,
        width=5cm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=1,
        % give `bar width' in axis units
        bar width=0.4,
        enlarge x limits={abs=0.6},
        legend columns=2,
        legend style={
            at={(0.5,1.22)},
            anchor=north,
        },
        xtick=data,
    ]
        \addplot table [x=x,y=y] {\data};
        \addplot table [x=x,y=z] {\data};
        \legend{y, z}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]